# How to set the span element at the bottom of span element next to it and ellipsis using css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to set the Text in NumberAndText div to be at the level of the Number span and not be centered. i want to achieve like in image below.

[image]

And add some padding of 8px between Number and Text spans in NumberAndText div.

Also i want to set ellipsis for the Name div.

below is my code,

```
return (

    <Wrapper>
        <div>left side <div>
        <RightContainer>
            <Name>name</Name>
            <NumberAndText>
                <Number>200</Number>
                <Text>Text</Text>
            </NumberAndText>
        </RightContainer>
    </Wrapper>
);

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    margin-right: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;

 
const RightContainer = styled.div`
    //no styles yet
`;

const Name = styled.span`
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
`;

 const NumberAndText = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
 `;

  const Number = styled.span`
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 700;
 `;

  const Text = styled.span`
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
 `;
```

**what i have tried?**

for adding ellipsis to Name div added like below,

```
const Name = styled.span`
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
`;
```

but this for some reason doesnt work. also i dont know how to make the Text in NumberAndText div to look like in picture added.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: In the future please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Answer follows...

Comment: `align-items-fex-end`-`end`or `last baseline` maybe for `NumberAndText` instead `center` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, I have used "Roboto" font and adjusted the extra space at the bottom with line-height.

```css
.Wrapper {
    margin-right: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.RightContainer{
  padding: 1rem
}
.Name{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.NumberAndText { 
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
     align-items: flex-end;
     line-height: 1;
}
.Number {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #0095ff;
}
.Text {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     padding-left: 5px;
     line-height: 1.3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="LeftDiv">Left Side</div>
  <div class="RightContainer">
    <div class="Name">Name</div>
    <div class="NumberAndText">
     <div class="Number">300</div>
     <div class="Text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to align items by baseline use `align-items: baseline` rather than `align-items: center`.

In order for your overflow to work, there needs to be overflow to begin with. Unless you specify a constraint on the width of the span it will just grow to accommodate its content.

```css
#number-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#number {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 40px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="number-text">
  <span id="number">200</span>
  <span id="text">Text with overflow</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks align-items: baseline worked but the ellipsis doesnt work. even though i provide width for it. it is still taking parents div width.

Comment: adding display: flex and width truncates the text but doesnt show ellipsis.

Comment: Without more context or more complete code I can't answer further. The code snippet included in the answer is displaying correctly with ellipsis on both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: yep i have added width to both parent div and text and works.